# set width for text field in add record jtable

Tags: jtable, width

how can we set width in the textfield in add record pop up menu in jtable ?
the width is too narrow and i want to make it more wider.
this is the code for update in php code :

```
//Updating a record (updateAction)
else if($_GET["action"] == "update")
{
//Update record in database
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE datapelanggan SET pelanggan = '" . $_POST["pelanggan"] . "', cabang = " . $_POST["cabang"] . " WHERE ID = " . $_POST["ID"] . ";");

//Return result to jTable
$jTableResult = array();
$jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
print json_encode($jTableResult);
```

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase width of a textfield then just add width in style in your jtable javascript code

```
FNAME:{
    title: 'FIRST NAME',
    width: '8%',
    input: function(data)
    {
        if(data.record)
            return '<input type="text" value="' + data.record.FNAME + '" id="Edit-FNAME" name="FNAME" style="width:200px">';
        else
            return '<input type="text" value="" id="Edit-FNAME" name="FNAME" autofocus style="width:200px">';
    }
},
```